# How to execute the SQL where In query in swift and bind the params in the statement?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, sqlite, sqlite.swift

Below I am sharing my existing code which I have used for executing the where IN condition but now I am stuck in how to pass the values in the request.

```
public func getName(list: [String], class: String) -> [String] {
    let queryStatementString = "SELECT terms FROM termo WHERE terms IN =? AND class=?"
    var queryStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
    var arr : [String] = []
    
    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, queryStatementString, -1, &queryStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        if sqlite3_bind_text(queryStatement, 1,terminalNameList, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK {
            let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
            print("failure binding foo: \(errmsg)")
        }
        while sqlite3_step(queryStatement) == SQLITE_ROW {
            let ter = String(describing: String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, 0)))
            arr.append(ter)
        }
    } else {
        print("SELECT statement could not be prepared")
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(queryStatement)
    return arr
}
```

The below is my SQL query which I need to execute

```
let queryStatementString = "SELECT terms FROM termo WHERE terms IN =? AND class=?"
```

Here I am trying to pass the values

```
if sqlite3_bind_text(queryStatement, 1, list, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != 
 SQLITE_OK {
            let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
            print("failure binding foo: \(errmsg)")
        }
```

Please guys help me, Thanks in advance

Comment: What is this question about?  Is it about how to make a query with SQLite per se?  What are the objective-c and sqlite.swift tags for?

Comment: I am using SQLite in the swift in which I am stuck in the Where In a statement, so I am looking for the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can take the help of below example to build a select query with where clause

```
  let query = users.select(email)           // SELECT "email" FROM "users"
             .filter(name != nil)     // WHERE "name" IS NOT NULL
             .order(email.desc, name) // ORDER BY "email" DESC, "name"
             .limit(5, offset: 1)     // LIMIT 5 OFFSET 1
```

You can find more info [here](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/70fb7af324cb3170d921f135f0c84cbdb6487cc2/Documentation/Index.md)